# Gradients of lower layers of a CNN when gradient of an upper layer is 0?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, cnn, gradient-descent

Say we have a convolutional neural network with an input layer, 3 convolutional layers and an output layer.

Say the gradients with respect to the weights and biases of the third convolutional layer are all 0.

Then, by backpropagation and the chain rule, does this necessarily mean that the gradients with respect to the weights and biases of the first two convolutional layers are 0 too?

Comment: The major difference to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/122888/gradients-of-lower-layers-of-nn-when-gradient-of-an-upper-layer-is-0 is, that here the gradients of the last hidden (convolutional) layer is assumed to be zero. This might change the result.